# NHibernate Criteria: Subquery After 'From' Clause

Tags: sql, nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria

How can I write the following SQL using Criteria:

```
select b.Name as Batch, b.Capacity as Capecity, 
       a.tStudent as Admit, (b.Capacity-a.tStudent) as Availabe 
from ( 
 SELECT count(Id) as tStudent, BatchId FROM [dbo].[Student] group by BatchId) as a 
left join [dbo].[Batch] as b on a.BatchId = b.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use NHibernate, to produce query like this:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM 
( 
 SELECT ...
) AS a 
..
```

We have to options:

1. Map the sub-select as an Entity.
2. create raw SQL query

The first option would mean to create some `view`, and map it as an Entity. If we do not like view (or cannot create it) we can use the power of NHibernate mapping, element **`<subselect>`**:

```
<class name="MyEntity"... >
   <subselect>
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   </subselect>
   ...
```

The second option is about using NHibernate API to create native/raw SQL:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ")
```

It is not profiting from mapping, but we can still apply parameters, and profit from transformation...

[9.3.5. Queries in native SQL](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-nativesql)