# How to do you map an object to an aggregated view in NHibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Basically, I have an existing database I'm trying to map to with NHibernate.

Here's a simplified example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE exmplTable (
    id INT,
    changeNumber INT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255)   
)
```

which might contain the following records:

```
1  0 'John Doe' '123 Fake St'
1  1 'John Doe' '145 Another St' -- John moved
1  2 'John Doe' '42 Clark St'    -- John moved again
```

I only care about the most recent info for a single `id`. If I was to map these manually, I'd make a view:

```
SELECT id, name, address
FROM exmplTable E
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT id, MAX(changeNumber) cn
    FROM exmplTable
    GROUP BY id
) E2
ON E.id = E2.id AND E.changeNumber = E2.cn
```

and then get a record by id this way:

```
SELECT * FROM viewname WHERE id = @id
```

SO THEN:

Without making a view in the database, and without having an interface to the DAL to retrieve a record by manually performing the aggregate query, is it possible to just have NHibernate map to this sort of a relationship?

Note that although I am using NHibernate Hibernate xml works the same AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

In case, that we need to map some complex SELECT statements *(as the one mentioned above)* and we

1) do not want create view for that
2) can accept that solution will be readonly *(expectable, I know)*

We can use NHibernate built-in *(but not so deeply documented and presented)* feature `<subselect>`. Check here more details:

#### [NHibernate Criteria: Subquery After 'From' Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29739580/1679310)

small snippet example

```
<class name="MyEntity"... >
   <subselect>
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   </subselect>
   ...
```