# Can something like this be done in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-criteria

Not sure how to do this in Fluent NHibernate *(preferably)* or with `Criteria`.

```
SELECT foo.One, foo.Two, bar.One
FROM Bar bar
RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT 
             One, Two 
             WHERE One LIKE '%number%'
             ORDER BY Id ASC
             OFFSET 0 ROWS 
             FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY 
           ) Foo
ON Bar.Foo_Id = Foo.Id
WHERE Bar.Two IN (...)
```

Comment: No from clause in the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate `criteria`, represents a language for querying on **top of the Entities**, i.e. **on top of the *mapping***. That means, that we *(users of NHiernate criteria)* can effect the final SQL SELECT statement in these sections:

- `SELECT` *(either all mapped columns of the entity, or projections - just a specific columns)*
- `WHERE` *(any kind of restriction is available, including custom/DB specific statements)*
- `GROUP BY`
- `ORDER BY`
- `HAVING`

The fact, that we do query **Entities** *(i.e. how we mapped `<class name="MyEntity" table="MyTable"`)*, we can effect the **`FROM`** only inside of the mapping.

About the `JOIN`: we can also decide what will be joined *(which **mapped** reference)* and even the join type *(LEFT, INNER...)*. But the `ON` statement must contain NHibernate generated part, coming from the mapping.

So, the above was namely stated just to get to final statement:

If we want to have a SELECT as part of a FROM/JOIN ... that SELECT must be mapped as some Entity

```
<class name="MyEntity"... >
   <subselect>
    SELECT ...
    FROM ...
   </subselect>
```

Read more here:

#### [NHibernate Criteria: Subquery After 'From' Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29739580/1679310)